# Creating data frame from summary(); Error in dimnames(x) <- dnx : 'dimnames' applied to non-array

Tags: r, dataframe, summary

For the love of me, I don't understand why this does not work:

```
x = c(3, 5, 3, 100, 5, -9, 10, 24)
x_summary <- summary(x)
x_names <- names(x_summary)
x_summary <- unname(x_summary)
xdf <- data.frame(Statistics = x_names, Value = x_summary)
```

I thought the named vector from using `summary()` was the issue at first. But I don't understand why this yields the error: `Error in dimnames(x) <- dnx : 'dimnames' applied to non-array`

Comment: Try `tibble::tibble(Statistics = x_names, Value = x_summary)` and have a look at `class(x_summary)`.

Comment: Aha, I thought it was a named vector. Thank you very much. Do you want to write an answer of your solution or `as.vector(x_summary)` and I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`class(x_summary)` is of type `"summaryDefault" "table"` which seems to provide difficulties for `data.frame`. Either covert the class, e.g. `as.numeric(x_summary)`/`as.vector(x_summary)` or use other packages, e.g. `summary(x) |> broom::tidy()`. Note that `tibble::tibble(Statistics = x_names, Value = x_summary)` provides the dataframe you are looking for, but be careful with the class of `x_summary`.

```
data.frame(Statistics = x_names, Value = as.numeric(x_summary))

Statistics   Value
1       Min.  -9.000
2    1st Qu.   3.000
3     Median   5.000
4       Mean  17.625
5    3rd Qu.  13.500
6       Max. 100.000
```